# what do you think about this logo? what would you change? Some constructive criticism?

Tags: logo, critique

This is a logo for a photographer

[image]

Comment: Hi Ladvace, you will have better answers about your logo if you give some more information. Have a look to those recent questions:
 https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110925/120647     https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110792/120647

Comment: We have some [guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work). Can you please read these, and edit your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the business name is not well readable. The objective is not a proper O, more likely something is missing. I read it "N VI the hole in the middle obviously is O, so it's NOVI". Use a solid font instead.

If you use text as a part of a drawing, the rest of text can have same role.

An Example:

[image]

NOTE: This all is only an opinion. Other people can see things differently.

But in a traditional camera the prism is usually just above the objective. Consider to move yours a little.

Comment: I think the "Novi" in the original logo is pretty clear