# Critique: Logo for a sunglasses brand

Tags: logo, critique

Logo made for a sunglasses brand called Swole Shades, marketed towards fitness and bodybuilding niche. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks[image]

Comment: Hi keanul, read the [Critique Guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/120647) to get better answers for your logo. Also here are a couple of good examples of how to ask a logo critique question to get better answers: [Logo 1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110792/120647), [Logo 2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110925/120647)

Answer (score 10):

There is a strong, uncomfortable historical echo in that S form - unless you are deliberately courting neo-nazis, I'd consider a complete reconcept. Look up images of the "SS" collar tab - then redesign this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't unsee that one... Also might want to consider a horizontal version that may be more useable on the arm of a set of glasses.